# access static file in public_html/tmp without going trough controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have uploaded my cakephp app to cpanel and adjust and configure it to works with cpanel. Everything mostly works, however i find out that try to retrieve static file from tmp in public_html result in error. It tries to go to controller i think.

My structure is like this :

```
/cakephp139
          /cake
          /vendors
          /renttycoons  <= this is app folder
/public_html
          /tmp
          /js
          ....
```

I tried to access www.domain.com/tmp/test.csv, but result in errors although the test.csv was there. This is the error :
Error: The requested address '/403.shtml' was not found on this server.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

does it gives you cake like error? it seems like a permission error.

erorr 403 is forbidden error, not a not found or something like that. Your server gives you that error and tries to show you a page for that error that is not found so you are receiving a 404 for not having a page for a 403 error hehe.

It must be a permission error, try changing permission to 705 in the temp folder, your test.csv file included. If you are creating it with php, php normally creates them with the minimun permission, at least that happened to me... you may use chmod function in php to change the permissions after creating a file.